How to read data of cheque from HSP7000 star printer?
I have HSP7000 printer. following is device details.
https://starmicronics.com/support/products/hsp7000-support-page/
I'm using windows 10 so I have installed required drivers and lib.
and I have try to use PyUSB lib. of python to read data of cheque from HSP7000 as it's getting connected using USB to my system.
but I'm not able to read data.
does any one have any idea how to read data of cheque from HSP7000 machine?
getting error as  usb.core.NoBackendError: No backend available
to fix No backend available error I have try solution given in following link as well.
github.com/pyusb/pyusb/issues/340 still not got solution.
import usb.core
import usb.util

VENDOR_ID = 'VID_0519'
PRODUCT_ID = 'PID_0002'
# Find the device USB\VID_0519&PID_0002
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=VENDOR_ID, idProduct=PRODUCT_ID)  # Replace with your device's vendor and product IDs

dev.set_configuration()

def read_data():
    while True:
        try:
            data = dev.read(0x81, 64, timeout=100)  # Adjust endpoint and buffer size as needed
            print("Received:", data)
        except usb.core.USBError as e:
            print(e)

# Example: Start reading data
read_data()


Welcome to [so]. Please read How To Ask a Good Question. "please help me" is not a question; we don't write code to specification. You are expected to study the problem ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

@itprorh66 I have try to use serial lib and also use usb lib and above shared the code which I try for using USB lib try to read data. but in that I'm getting usb.core.NoBackendError: No backend available and try solution given in following link as well.
https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/issues/340
still not got solution so I'm asking the question.
so don't just tell anyone "please help me and etc" without knowing what person have try.

You are exactly illustrating the point I was trying to make.  The fact that you are getting a specific error, and the steps taken to resolve the error should be part of your original question.
